# Storing String content in map on the basis of <key, value> c++

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, stl, unordered-map

I have a string "parrot -color green -peak". I want to store this string in map with <key, value> format. where in this first string is considered as binary executable object rest of the values should be stored in map<key, value> format, where (-string represents key) the very next string considered as value for that particular key. if the value is empty it should store as empty string. But from my code its storing key as value. please also check mentioned expected output and result observed from existing code for better understanding. Thanks in advance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    string s = "parrot -color green -peak";
    char sep = '-';
    map<string, string> clArgs;
    
    // find first '-' and copy contents
    string executable_name = s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(sep));
    cout << "exec name = " << executable_name << endl;
    
    s.erase(0, s.find_first_of(sep));
    cout << "s = " << s << endl;
    
    // iterate over string and copy key-value pairs
    int pos;
    while ((pos = s.find_first_of(sep, 1)) != string::npos)
    {
        string keyVal = s.substr(0, pos);
        s = s.substr(pos);
        
        string key, value;
        key = keyVal.substr(0, keyVal.find_first_of(' '));
        keyVal = keyVal.substr(keyVal.find_first_of(' ')+1);
        value = keyVal.substr(0, keyVal.find_first_of(' '));
        clArgs[key] = value;
    }
    
    if (s.length() != 0)
    {
        // there is still last command line arg remaining
        // need to process it as well
        clArgs[s.substr(0, s.find_first_of(' '))] = s.substr(s.find_first_of(' ')+1);
    }
    
    cout << "Printing key-value pairs ...\n";
    for (map<string, string>::iterator it = clArgs.begin(); it != clArgs.end(); it++)
    {
        cout << "(key = " << it->first << ", value = " << it->second << ")\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
output from above code:-

exec name = parrot 
s = -color green -peak
Printing key-value pairs ...
(key = -color, value = green)
(key = -peak, value = -peak)
```

```
expected output:-

exec name = parrot 
s = -color green -peak
Printing key-value pairs ...
(key = -color, value = green)
(key = -peak, value = )
```

Comment: A command-line parser implementation should be a little more sophisticated than what you've implemented.  Right now, you don't have any indication of what command should or should not have parameters.  Is it possible for `-peak` to have a value?  If a value is required, then that should be an error -- you shouldn't burden yourself with trying to store blank strings.

Comment: It would be a good idea to check whether the `find_first_of`s actually find anything.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it is not necessarily we should be having values. in this example -peak

Comment: @molbdnilo thanks for suggesting. ill give a try :)

Comment: You should attempt to make your command-line parser behave in a way that other parsers work.  You should have set up a `struct` that describes the characteristics of each of the commands, i.e. the name of the command, whether the command must have an argument, etc.   Then create an array, map, whatever, of structs.  Then parse each `-` token, match it with the struct to see if the command must have an argument.  Then the code you've written to get the argument comes into play.  Right now, you assume that every command has an argument, which obviously is not true.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie can you please elaborate with an example!

Comment: There should be plenty of C++ examples on the web of generic command-line parsing.  It's obvious that each type of command would have various characteristics such as whether it is specified without any option, whether it must be specified with an option, whether the command itself is optional and need not appear, the available options that the command can have, etc.  Merely assuming that a command has an option is not the way this is done in the real-world environment.  Even for your simple case, it gets very messy and confusing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it will be more helpful. if you provide better site links.. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is rather complicated and could benefit from using `std::stringstream` and `std::getline`. The string functions are very suspectible to passing invalid indices. I suggest you to use a debugger to find where your expectations are off.  Splitting strings is straightforward with `getline` and a stream. A slightly simpler version could look like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    string s = "parrot -color green -peak";
    char sep = '-';
    map<string, string> clArgs;

    // extract first word
    std::stringstream ss{s};    
    std::string exec_name;
    std::getline(ss,exec_name,sep);
    
    // extract portions of the string separated by -
    std::string key_value_pair;
    while (std::getline(ss,key_value_pair,sep)) {
        // now extract first and second word 
        std::stringstream skvp{key_value_pair};
        std::string key;
        std::string value;
        skvp >> key >> value;
        clArgs[key] = value;
    }

    std::cout << exec_name << "\n";
    
    cout << "Printing key-value pairs ...\n";
    for (const auto& e : clArgs)
    {
        cout << "(key = " << e.first << ", value = " << e.second << ")\n";
    }
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/qcfxrsd6d):

```
parrot 
Printing key-value pairs ...
(key = color, value = green)
(key = peak, value = )
```

Comment: the key should have "hyphen(-)". from your code "hyphen(-)" is missing!

Comment: @Amith Kotian thats because `getline` reads everything but discards the delimiter. You can of course add it back

Answer (score 3):

1. If a parameter string is optional then I suggest you parse your input into tokens then process token by token.
2. You are currently assuming the value of a key/value pair is always present. You do not check for the presence of a value after searching for a space character.

Answer (score 1):

```
key = keyVal.substr(0, keyVal.find_first_of(' '));
keyVal = keyVal.substr(keyVal.find_first_of(' ')+1);
value = keyVal.substr(0, keyVal.find_first_of(' '));
```

`s` is "-peak" on the second iteration. `keyVal.find_first_of(' ')` is `npos` and access to the chars by `keyVal.find_first_of(' ')+1` is not what you expect. You should check it for `npos` before incrementing.

```
auto space = keyVal.find_first_of(' ');
key = keyVal.substr(0, space);
if (space != keyVal.npos) {
  keyVal = keyVal.substr(space + 1);
  value = keyVal.substr(0, keyVal.find_first_of(' '));
} else {
  keyVal = "";
  value = "";
}
```

Comment: `((unsigned type) -1)+1` would be `0`, not UB afaict.

Comment: well `string.substr(0)` returns an exact copy, not UB

Comment: @S.M.  suggested code isn't helping much
  `int pos;
  while ((pos = s.find_first_of(sep, 1)) != string::npos)
  {
  string keyVal = s.substr(0, pos);
  s = s.substr(pos);
  string key, value;
  auto space = keyVal.find_first_of(' ');
        key = keyVal.substr(0, space);
        if (space != keyVal.npos)
  {
           keyVal = keyVal.substr(space + 1);
           value = keyVal.substr(0, keyVal.find_first_of(' '));
  } 
        else
     {
           keyVal = "";
           value = "";
        }
        clArgs[key] = value;
     }`

Comment: @S.M. please see the code snippet in previous comment with changes suggested. let me know is what the changes you meant